# Lightswitch multiple grids on same page from the same entity causing issue when adding a new item

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

We have a entity called workingfields based on a sql table.  There is a type field in this table so we can store different types of working fields all in the same table.  We then have 5 different grids on one screen that are based on the workingfields entity but each is based on a separate query we created off of the workingfields that filters it by a specific type of working field.

So our grids each only show the items that match that type.  When we add a new item to one of the grids, it adds it to the bottom of all of the grids.  If we hit save and refresh, it will save it with the right type because we are setting that when we add a new entity in the grid and it goes away on the other grids when we refresh the screen.  But, Its like the queries filter for the grids to show us the data we want but since they are all based on the same entity called workingfields lightswitch thinks we want to add new to the entity and it shows it on all the grids even though we want it to show on only one grid.  Is there a way we can only have it add new on the specific grid we want and not on the entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe obvious, but have you tried breaking each grid out into its own separate screen?